# Redis Timeout using Servicestack

Tags: c#, .net-core, servicestack

We use Service stack as our RedisClient.

Our application handles above 50 requests per second and the current architecture is that 12 load balanced application instances all connect to a single Redis instance with get/set operations queued using Hangfire.

We use PooledRedisClientManager with the configuration below:

```
services.AddSingleton<IRedisClientsManager>(p =>
           new PooledRedisClientManager(Configuration.GetValue<long>("Redis:DatabaseId"), Configuration.GetValue<string>("Redis:master"))
           {
               ConnectTimeout = Configuration.GetValue<int>(5000),
               IdleTimeOutSecs = Configuration.GetValue<int>(30),
               PoolTimeout = Configuration.GetValue<int>(3)
           });
```

Our Applications have been throwing this exception:

```
Redis Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use.
   at ServiceStack.Redis.PooledRedisClientManager.GetClient(Boolean forAsync) in C:\BuildAgent\work\b2a0bfe2b1c9a118\src\ServiceStack.Redis\PooledRedisClientManager.cs:line 264
```

I'm aware the maximum number of connected clients to Redis is 10000 and we only had 594 clients connected to the Redis Instance.

Kindly assist

Answer (score 0):

You've reached the Pool Size of the `PooledRedisClientManager` which when it reaches its limit blocks until a new client is released back into the pool or times out if the Timeout is exceeded.

You can configure the pool size with:

```
RedisConfig.DefaultMaxPoolSize = ...
```

Alternatively you may want to switch to the [RedisManagerPool](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redismanagerpool) which when it exceeds the pool size will create/release clients outside of the pool, instead of blocking.

Comment: Thanks @mythz. I could only get RedisClientManagerConfig on PooledRedisClientManager is it an update or am i missing something.